# Parse Syntax error with Create Function for Splitting Words SQL

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am using the following code, but getting the following error - what is going on!! to me everything looks good, but I am new to Create or Replace Functions - so perhaps that's it. I am looking to take a giant set of chats and analyze and changes in frequency that certain terms are used each day:

> Error: [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'LANGUAGE'.line 4,
> pos 7

Code:

```
-- Function to split text into words
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SplitWords(input_text TEXT) RETURNS TABLE (word TEXT) AS $$
    SELECT regexp_split_to_table(input_text, '\s') AS word
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

-- Query to count term occurrences per conversation
SELECT
    ChatID,
    Disposition,
    word,
    COUNT(*) AS TermCount
FROM
    chat_log_10_14_10_16,
    LATERAL SplitWords(ConversationText) AS words
GROUP BY
    ChatID,
    Disposition,
    word
ORDER BY
    ChatID,
    TermCount DESC;

-- Query to analyze changes in term frequency over multiple days
SELECT
    word,
    ConversationDate,
    COUNT(*) AS TermCount
FROM
    chat_log_10_14_10_16,
    LATERAL SplitWords(ConversationText) AS words
GROUP BY
    word,
    ConversationDate
ORDER BY
    word,
    ConversationDate;
```

I am hoping to get a list of "Words" and the # of times they were used each day.

```
Ex. 
10/14 
The 1000
Buy 500
Want 400
Can 2000
I 50000

10/15
The 3000
Buy 300
Want 100
Can 20000
I 300000
```

Comment: Tried `'\\s'` yet?

Comment: doesnt fix it - then I get "[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near end of input: extra input end of input.line "

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for creating funtion using sql language.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SplitWords(input_text string) 
  RETURNS TABLE (word ARRAY<STRING>)
  return SELECT split(input_text, '\\s') AS word
```

What you have given is `dollar_quoted_definition`
which is Python function `body` enclosed by `$$` dollar.

Query 1

```
select ChatID,Disposition,word,count(*) as TermCount
from 
(select ChatID,Disposition,ConversationDate,ConversationText,explode(words.word) as word from 
chat_log_10_14_10_16,
LATERAL SplitWords(ConversationText) AS words)
group by 
ChatID,
Disposition,
word
ORDER BY
    ChatID,
    TermCount DESC;
```

| ChatID | Disposition | Word | Term Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Positive | l | 1 |
| 1 | Positive | a | 1 |
| 1 | Positive | Laptop | 1 |

Query 2

```
SELECT
    tmp,
    ConversationDate,
    COUNT(*) AS TermCount
FROM
(select ConversationDate,ConversationText,explode(words.word) as tmp from 
chat_log_10_14_10_16,
LATERAL SplitWords(ConversationText) AS words)
GROUP BY
    tmp,
    ConversationDate
ORDER BY
ConversationDate DESC;
```

| tmp | ConversationDate | Term Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| laptop | 2023-10-16 | 1 |
| laptop? | 2023-10-16 | 1 |
| I | 2023-10-16 | 1 |
| Can | 2023-10-16 | 1 |
| still | 2023-10-16 | 1 |
| assist | 2023-10-16 | 1 |
| need | 2023-10-16 | 1 |